Rotate vector by quaternion different formulas
I was implementing the rotation of a 3D vector by a quaternion, implementing the formula that I've found in this thread.
To testing my function, I've rotated some vectors by using MATLAB, in particular the quatrotate formula.
All the test that I've made failed. After checking it a bit, I've noticed that in the thread the definition of vector rotation was performed by following formula in the original thread:
$$p' = q \times p \times q*$$
where
$$p = (v_x, v_y, v_z, 0) \Leftrightarrow p = (v, 0)$$
Instead, in the MATLAB help page, the definition is different:

The Aerospace Toolbox defines a passive quaternion rotation of the form:
$$v'=q^{-1}\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{0}{v} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes q
$$
where \$\otimes\$ is the operator of a quaternion multiplication.

If I write the MATLAB definition formula in my code, all tests pass, so at least my quaternion class is correct (I've performed a lot of other tests about multiplications, conjugate etc. and all of them seems correct).
So I'd like to know what's the differences between the formulas, and which one should I pick in order to correctly rotate the vector.

Are all the quaternions you use normalised?

Yes, I normalize them before performing operations.

Elsewhere on the linked page, it says:

Aerospace Toolbox uses quaternions that are defined using the scalar-first convention.

meaning, the vector \$(a,b,c,d)\$ represents the quaternion \$a + bi + cj + dk\$.
The other Stack Exchange question you link to uses scalar-last convention, i.e. the vector \$(a,b,c,d)\$ represents the quaternion \$ai + bj + ck + d\$.
Either convention is fine, just make sure to be consistent.

The aerospace/NASA quaternion strikes again!!!
